# 02 Escape still sucking air after new upper and lower air intake gaskets

Tags: escape, vacuum-leak

I can hear it. Plus acceleration is slow and the EGR keeps going off. I have replaced the EGR with a junkyard one and it didn't fix the problem so I want to fix the vacuum leak before I spend money on a new EGR.

I cleaned the whole area when I put the new gaskets on. But I don't think the lower intake lined up perfectly. I mean, all four bolt holes lined up but it still appeared off and like the gasket might not be perfectly seated in the groove on the head. Maybe I could get it to fit better if I messed with it but I figured that must be as good as it gets.

Anyways I tightened with 3 rounds of 3,2,4,1 but I just went to pretty tight on my 1/4" drive socket wrench.

It's still sucking air. Maybe it's just a line somewhere. Maybe I am mistaking air swooshing around by the serpentine belt as a vacuum leak. But I think the intake is leaking somewhere. Propane around the intake doesn't change the engine. Not brave enough to spray brake cleaner down there.

Should I try the intake one more time? Try the EGR? Give up and take it to a pro?

Comment: Seems like a question that was asked just the other day. Gave a couple of comments about possible ways to check.

Comment: I believe you suggested that I plugged the exhaust and pressurize the system but when I asked how to do those things you never clarified and I'm not sure what I'm looking for when doing such a test anyways. I'm not saying it's not a good test I'm just saying I don't know what I'm supposed to be looking for or how to do it oh what the name of the test is or if I would expect to detect something with that test that I wouldn't detect with other tests etc.

Comment: You were told to use a rag...

Comment: You are looking for a leak.

Comment: Does not have a particular name afaik.

Comment: when I asked you how to plug and charge the system someone suggested using a rag to plug the system but neither you nor the other person has said how one might go about charging the system and I just found out that the thing that I would be looking for is a leak and I don't know how that's supposed to work any better then just running the engine and listening for the location of the leak.